# call function from function python

Tags: python, function

I am doing a simple calculation for burning calories.
I am getting data and variables from users and I have two formulas.

The BMR function works. The tee keeps throwing errors (mostly on cannot call a float) and when it does not I get something like `<function a0…>`.

```
def bmr(gender, age, height, weight):
    if gender == "f":
        bmr = 655 + weight*9.6 + height*1.6 + age*4.7
    else:
        bmr = 66 + weight*13.8 + height*5 + age*6.8
    return bmr

def tee (bmr, amount_of_exersice):
    #x = 0
    y = bmr(gender, age, height, weight)
    if amount_of_exersice == 0:
        x = 1.2
    elif 1<= amount_of_exersice <= 2:
        x = 1.375
    elif 3 <= amount_of_exersice <= 5:
        x = 1.55
    else:
        x = 1.725
    z = x * y
    return z
```

Comment: how do you call `tee` ? also state the error and where it comes in the function clearly and I don't see you define `gender, age, height, weight` when you call `bmr(gender, age, height, weight)` in `tee`

Comment: what's the argument bmr doing in tee ?

Comment: BMR Female = 655 + weight*9.6 + height*1.8 + age*4.7\\
BMR Male = 66 + weight*13.8 + height*5 + age*6.8\\
if Amount of exercise days per week = 0 then TEE = BMR*1.2 \\
if Amount of exercise days per week = 1-2 then TEE = BMR*1.375\\
if Amount of exercise days per week = 3-5 then TEE = BMR*1.55\\
if Amount of exercise days per week = 6-7 then TEE = BMR*1.725

Comment: Please don't add code in comments, instead [edit] the question. Code in the question can be formatted properly, code in comments is very hard to read.

Comment: The text was all wrong.  No punctuation, missing or incomplete words, ...

Comment: You don't have the arguments being passed to bmr within tee as they are not arguments to tee.  Even if they are globals (bad idea) there should be a globals statement declaring them in tee.  But wait tee takes a parameter called bmr.  So why are we using this parameter which is likely the result of a previous call to bmr as a function?  So the parameter name is asking for confusion.   Or did you mean for tee to be a higher order function receiving a function parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of problems, you're redefining "bmr" and you're not passing the right arguments to second bmr call. Try, as example:

```py
def tee (gender, age, height, weight, amount_of_exersice):
    y = bmr(gender, age, height, weight)
    if amount_of_exersice == 0:
        x = 1.2
    elif 1<= amount_of_exersice <= 2:
        x = 1.375
    elif 3 <= amount_of_exersice <= 5:
        x = 1.55
    else:
        x = 1.725
    z = x * y
    return z
```

or if you want to define bmr before:

```py
def tee (y, amount_of_exersice):
    if amount_of_exersice == 0:
        x = 1.2
    elif 1<= amount_of_exersice <= 2:
        x = 1.375
    elif 3 <= amount_of_exersice <= 5:
        x = 1.55
    else:
        x = 1.725
    z = x * y
    return z

y_bmr = bmr(gender, age, height, weight)
tee(y_bmr, amount_of_exersice)
```

Comment: the first one worked perfectly. the second is more elegant but still give me errors.

Comment: sorry, I did not change the bmr-y value, it should work now

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
def tee(bmr, amount_of_exersize):
```

You're redefining the name `bmr` to point to whatever variable you're passing in - whereas, if you hadn't done that, it would have referred to the function above. This replacement applies so long as you're within the method, and the only real solution is to rename the parameter so that it doesn't conflict:

```
def tee(something_else, amount_of_exersize):
    y = bmr(gender, age, height, weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def validate_user_input(prompt, type_=None, min_=None, max_=None, range_=None):
    if min_ is not None and max_ is not None and max_ < min_:
        raise ValueError("min_ must be less than or equal to max_.")
    while True:
        ui = input(prompt)
        if type_ is not None:
            try:
                ui = type_(ui)
            except ValueError:
                print("Input type must be {0}.".format(type_.__name__))
                continue
        if max_ is not None and ui > max_:
            print("Input must be less than or equal to {0}.".format(max_))
        elif min_ is not None and ui < min_:
            print("Input must be greater than or equal to {0}.".format(min_))
        elif range_ is not None and ui not in range_:
            if isinstance(range_, range):
                template = "Input must be between {0.start} and {0.stop}."
                print(template.format(range_))
            else:
                template = "Input must be {0}."
                if len(range_) == 1:
                    print(template.format(*range_))
                else:
                    print(template.format(" or ".join((", ".join(map(str,
                                                                     range_[:-1])),
                                                       str(range_[-1])))))
        else:
            return ui


def bmr(gender, age, height, weight):
    if gender == "f":
        bmr = 655 + weight*9.6 + height*1.6 + age*4.7
    else:
        bmr = 66 + weight*13.8 + height*5 + age*6.8
    return bmr

def tee (gender, age, height, weight, amount_of_exersice):
    y = bmr(gender, age, height, weight)
    if amount_of_exersice == 0:
        x = 1.2
    elif 1<= amount_of_exersice <= 2:
        x = 1.375
    elif 3 <= amount_of_exersice <= 5:
        x = 1.55
    else:
        x = 1.725
    z = x * y
    return z

## user info ##
gender = validate_user_input("Please enter your gender (F -Female / M- Male): ", str.lower, range_=("f","m"))
age = validate_user_input("Please enter your age: ", int, 1, 110)
height = validate_user_input("Please enter your height in cm: ", int, 130, 230)
weight = validate_user_input("Please enter your weight in kg: ", float, 20, 400)
amount_of_exersice = validate_user_input("Please enter the amount of days you engage in physical activity per week: ", int, 0, 7)

calc_bmr = bmr(gender, age, height, weight)
calc_tee = tee(gender, age, height, weight, amount_of_exersice)
print("Your Basal Metabolic Rate is ", calc_bmr)
print("Your daily calories burn is ", calc_tee)
```